# When do games become available on "Games on Demand"?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

I want to purchase NFS:Most Wanted through xbox live, however NFS:MW is not available there. When should I expect it to be available on "Games on Demand" ? Do games have a generic time duration before release ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Release dates for Games on Demand games are not really predictable.  Some games never see a GoD release, while others come out within a few months of the disc release.  Barring any prerelease information from a credible source, you won't know when the release will occur until it does.